# I want to select many columns from many tables without foreign key

Tags: mysql, join, select, code

I have three tables, and I want to fetch the three table data without a foreign key.

Say I have a table product_1 which contains (id, name) and table product_2 contain (id, name, price).

I want to select the columns of the two tables in one query.

I am asking if there are any MySQL query to select many columns from many tables?

This is my code:

```
SELECT name FROM product1 AND price FROM product2;
```

Comment: It may be `UNION`you are looking for. Otherwise, add an example as a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 and the expected result

Comment: Do they have the same name?  Or are the two rows unrelated?

Comment: SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.field_x = t2.field_y?

Answer (score 0):

> I have three tables, and I want to fetch the three table data without a foreign key.

I *think* you mean "without a join condition".
That's a Bad Idea.

If you don't tell the database how to join *two* tables, it will perform a **Cartesian Join**, i.e. it will match *every* row in the first table against *every* row in the second table.

- If you have *ten* rows in both tables, you will get back a resultset of one hundred (10 x 10) rows.
- If you have a million rows in both tables, you will get back a resultset of **one trillion** (10^6 x 10^6) rows - assuming your database survives long enough to deliver it and you're prepared to wait that long!

And the *more* tables you add, the *more* this multiplies out!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, p.price
    FROM Names  AS a
    JOIN Prices AS p  ON p.id = a.id AND p.name = a.name;
```

This works with or without indexes, with or without `FOREIGN KEYs`.  But performance is better *with*.